How to generate X25519 key pairs with length 44 characters in Base64?
I am a java programmer. I am intended to generate a set of keypair with "X25519" instance.
I am using JDK 8, hence I am implementing BouncyCastle library to achieve this.
The BC version I am using is bcprov-jdk18on-1.78.1.jar which I get it from the official website.
I have tried to use the code below to get the result.
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class X25519KeyGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Generate X25519 key pair using Bouncy Castle
            KeyPair keyPair = generateX25519KeyPair();

            // Get private and public keys
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            // Encode keys in Base64 format
            String privateKeyBase64 = encodeKeyToBase64(privateKey);
            String publicKeyBase64 = encodeKeyToBase64(publicKey);

            System.out.println("Private Key (Base64): " + privateKeyBase64);
            System.out.println("Public Key (Base64): " + publicKeyBase64);
            System.out.println("Private Key Length: " + privateKeyBase64.length());
            System.out.println("Public Key Length: " + publicKeyBase64.length());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Generate X25519 key pair using Bouncy Castle
    public static KeyPair generateX25519KeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("X25519", "BC");
        return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    // Encode key to Base64 format
    public static String encodeKeyToBase64(Key key) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded());
    }
}

The result I got from the code is as below.
Private Key (Base64): MFECAQEwBQYDK2VuBCIEIPAZWyLiw7qF9UaND6hFp+cJPvcl4TiDY+ab9s9vBrlkgSEAWvvMm0LCB0qzTa68jQ0gvB48ZqsOR6LRmFZdw0aT4kM= 
Public Key (Base64): MCowBQYDK2VuAyEAWvvMm0LCB0qzTa68jQ0gvB48ZqsOR6LRmFZdw0aT4kM= 
Private Key Length: 112 
Public Key Length: 60

I was expecting it to be 44 in length. May I know what is the possible issue with this?

(base64(x)).length == x.length/2*3

The posted private key has the PKCS#8 format, the public key the X.509/SPKI format (both are DER encoded keys that you have Base64 encoded for output). With regard to the length of 32 bytes (44 bytes Base64 encoded), you are probably looking for the raw keys. These are located at the end of the DER encoded PKCS#8 and X.509/SPKI formatted key and can therefore be determined as the last 32 bytes in each case. Alternatively, you can extract them with BouncyCastle (using BC's PrivateKeyFactory.createKey() and X25519PrivateKeyParameters for the private key and analogously for the public key).
